# uninstall visual studio 2015 shell (isolated)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My SQL Server Management studio was running perfectly before. I deleted some random folder (don't remember what it was) and it stopped running. When i repaired it, it wouldn't run. It would display an error message saying "**one or more component is missing. Please re-install**". The same message would show up even after re-install. So i decided to do a full uninstall and install again. **I** **managed to remove everything except for visual studio 2015 shell (isolated)**.  When i hit uninstall, it displays the message in first image and when clicked yes, it shows the error in second image.
Any idea how to get rid of this and get ssms.exe running properly?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmya, this is the way the users turn their expensive computer into a little heap of useless beach sand.  Can't uninstall anymore, can't reinstall because there is too much junk left in the registry.  Very hard to get rid of.  Only shot you have is to rerun the SDK installer with /uninstall /force, it will make a "best effort" and plow on, ignoring errors.  Could work.  Big changes in the VS2017 installer to avoid these kind of traps.

Answer (score 0):

i) Download TotalUninstaller.zip from here,
https://github.com/microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases/download/v1.4/TotalUninstaller.zip

ii) Unzip
iii)Open CMD in admin mode
iv) run the Setup.ForcedUninstall.exe (by typing it in CMD after navigating to correct directory)
v) Press Y then press ENTER

This should clear out uninstallable VS2015 isolated shell, along with other VS2015 components